# Returning a struct without initializing it

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a very simple color struct like this

```
struct {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
} RGBA;
```

Now in some function, I would like to return a structure like this.

But I can't figure out how to do that. All I can think of is creating a local structure, filling each field separately, and then returning it.

```
RGBA localStructure;
localStructure.red = r;
localStructure.green = g;
localStructure.blue = b;
localStructure.alpha = a;
return localStructure;
```

Where I really would like to do something like this

```
return RGBA(r,g,b,a);
```

is there a way to achieve this in C/C++?

Comment: You need to decide whether this is C or C++. For C++ use a constructor. For C use a function.

Comment: @Paul, don't need a function for C. A compound literal would do.

Comment: No matter language, never return a whole struct (or object) by value. It doesn't make any sense, nor does it improve readability, it just slows down the code. If you must call a function, pass a struct by ref, then fiddle around with it.

Comment: @Lundin: you are forgetting about NRVO which many modern compilers (gcc, msvc) implement. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: @Lundin: we're talking about a 4 byte struct here - and there's no need for *premature optimisation*.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: compound literals are only available in C99, no - not in C in general ?

Comment: @Paul, "C in general" is just a fiction, this doesn't exist. You will always find such and such compiler that doesn't support a particular feature. This supported by the international C standard, C99, plus other compilers that implement it as an extension to C89 mode.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: until MS support C99 in Visual Studio I don't think you can just glibly assume that C99 support is ubiquitous.

Comment: @Paul, I did say that. But Visual Studio is not "C in general" either. Programming in C with MS tools is simply not fully supported, they don't want you to do this, and they want you to use their proprietary tools, instead. So if on MS, if you insist to use C, better use a modern C compiler that is standard complying.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: unfortunately in the real world most people don't have a choice as to which compiler they use. If you work for a company that uses C on Windows then you are most likely stuck with Visual Studio, execrable though it is, and C99 is not available to you.

Comment: @Evan There is no guarantee by any programming standard that such an optimization is done (unless you inline). From the little I know of NRVO, it is an optimization eliminating copy constructor + destructor calls. If that is correct, it would only apply to C++ and not C. Besides that, it really doesn't make any *sense* to return by value programming-wise. Because the value you return must afterwards be stored in some other variable that is already allocated. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Paul From the general programming point-of-view we are using here, you can't state how large a struct is, because of mentioned padding, which is implementation-defined. Also, if this is compiled in C++ you may get additional class-related overhead allocated with the struct. From the same point-of-view, you can't tell if ~4 bytes is small or large.  On an 8-bit MCU, returning ~4 bytes by value is highly suspicious, while it likely doesn't matter on a desktop PC. Since nobody has mentioned PC anywhere, there is no need for premature system assumptions.

Comment: @Lundin: some valid points, but in the general case it's better to write simple, clear, easily understood code that is robust, reliable and portable in the first instance. If there are any significant performance issues subsequently then they can be identified and optimised later, but only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Paul But passing structs by reference is the simple, easily understood way of doing this in the C language. I can not come up with any commercial software library that does return structs by value. Returning them by reference through one of the parameters is industry standard, every single API I can think of does this, from Win32 to embedded hw-peripheral software stacks. If you get confused by that syntax, you are getting confused by the C language. I never quite understood why people insist I should adapt my syntax so it can be read by non-programmers.

Comment: @Lundin: C doesn't have references, I expect you mean C++, or perhaps pointers in C ? Also note that for small structs such as the one in question, if you are concerned about performance etc then it will be better to pass the whole 4 byte struct in a register than to pass a pointer to it.

Comment: @Paul "By reference" is a general programming term. "By pointer" and "by reference" means the same thing, and they yield exactly the same machine code. You can learn about it in the C standard 9899:1999 §6.2.5.20: "A *pointer type* may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete type, called the *referenced type*. A pointer type describes an object whose value
provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type."

Comment: @Paul As for performance concerns, leave that to the compiler. The programmer shouldn't put parameters in registers, that's the compiler's job, depending on the application's calling convention.

Comment: @Lundin: the optimization has been common in the mainstream compilers for a long time. So while you are right that it isn't guaranteed to happen, it is very likley unless you are working with a less common compiler. You pointed out that "it doesn't make sense" since the result needs to be stored in another variable. The thing is, the optimization is not just about constructors and such, it is specifically that the compiler can construct the result **directly** in that other location. So you end up with code which is simple (just returns a thing) and is efficient.

Comment: @Evan Is this common in C compilers as well? I have only encountered it for C++ on various Windows compilers so far.

Comment: @Lundin: in the end, it is pretty much universally considered better code if you write what you mean, and worry about optimization **if** that line turns out to be a performance issue (which in this case of returning a 32-bit struct certainly won't be). Heck, passing a reference and putting the data there may be **less** efficient due to the indirection here, since the entire struct can fit in a register (assuming this is x86/x86-64)!

Comment: @Lundin: it may be c++ specific, to be honest I am not sure. There is a clause in the standard that is an exception to the "you can optimize however you like as long as there is no change in observable behavior" rule. Since constructors and such are observable, they had to make a special rule allowing this optimization. However, I don't see why c compiler couldn't do such an optimization. All it would have to do is detect that a single struct is allocated on the stack, populated by the function and returned by copy. Same rules as c++, just no constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, in your first snippet, RGBA is an object whose type is an unnamed struct I don't think that's what you intended. You probably meant either:

```
typedef struct { ... } RGBA; /* what a lot of C programmers do */
```

or

```
struct RGBA { ... }; /* probably what you meant */
```

---

Anyway, to answer your question, give it a constructor!

```
struct RGBA {
    RGBA(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a) : red(r), green(g), blue(b), alpha(a) {
    }

    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
};
```

Then you can write:

```
return RGBA(r,g,b,a);
```

Comment: @peoro: correct, but it does let the OP write the exact code he wanted to :-).

Comment: Does this change the size of the struct? It must be convertible into a `uint32` here and there.

Comment: @BasitBechtold: no, adding non-virtual member functions to a struct/class in c++ has no effect on the size of the struct/class. But if you really need to convert to `uint32_t` and you are using c++, it is probably nicer to have a `to_uint32_t()` method. But that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 3):

In C you can initialize structures with this *shortcut*:

```
RGBA x = { r, g, b, a };
```

So a quick way to do what you want could be this one:

```
return (RGBA) { r, g, b, a };
```

Comment: is that second snippet only for c99? I think anonymous arrays were introduced in c99.

Comment: @Evan, yes compound literals are only in the C99 standard.

Comment: @Evan Teran: the second example is only for C99, it's called a "compound literal". You can also initialize arrays that way, like (int[]) {1,2,3,4};

Comment: I would bet that at least one of the compilers this has to be compiled on will not understand C99.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a struct can have a constructor.

```
struct RGBA{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;

    RGBA( unsigned char _red, unsigned char _green, unsigned char _blue, unsigned char _alpha ) : red( _red ), green( _green ), blue( _blue ), alpha( _alpha )
    {}

};
```

Answer (score 2):

`struct { ... } RGBA` defines an object RGBA of an unnamed struct. What you probably mean is `typedef struct { ... } RGBA;`. Then you can do:

```
RGBA fun() {
    RGBA obj = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0 };
    return obj;
}
```

[GCC supports compound C99 literals in C90 mode and in C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals), so than you can do:

```
RGBA fun() {
    return ((RGBA){ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, declare a constructor.

```
struct RGBA { 

   RGBA(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned b, unsigned char a = 0xff)
     : red(r)
     , green(g)
     , blue(b)
     , alpha(a)
   {
   }

   ...
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
 RGBA t = RGBA(0xff,0xff,0);
```

or this

```
 return RGBA(0,0,0,0xff);
```

Note: constructors are an essential C++ feature. You should definitely read up on object orientation in C++. It will make your life much happier.

Comment: Note: I do know about constructors. It does strike me as odd that a struct would have one, though. After all, object orientation is about classes and class instances, not structs.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are virtually synonym in C++, except that the default visibility of `struct` members is `public` rather than `private`. Apart from that they're the same. However, it's very common to use `struct` for pure, plain data structures with no further methods. Adding a constructor that only initializes all members is not really a reason to make it a class by this convention.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your RGBA struct is unable to be changed, e.g. 3rd party or needs to be in C, and your wish to simplify your return in C++, then you can define an initialisor type to do the work:

```
struct RGBAInitialisor
{
    RGBAInitialisor(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a) {
        impl_.alpha = a;
        impl_.blue = b;
        impl_.green = g;
        impl_.red = r;
    }
    // This converts back to the RGBA on the fly.
    operator RGBA ()
    {
        return impl_;
    }
    RGBA impl_;

};

RGBA f()
{
    return RGBAInitialisor(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class instead of a struct (or keep it a struct) and give it a constructor with the 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ struct is really a class, so you can add a constructor to it, and then provide code to initialize the fields in the constructor.

A C struct has a size, so if you want to initialize all of the fields, you can generally

```
RGBA localStructure;
memset(&localStructure, 0, sizeof(localStructure));
```